# How to add a custom CSS to a Store View?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, store-view

I have a Shop running on Magento 1.9.2 with a Storeview and got the request to add a Storeview for a different Country with the exact same look.

My Problem is that the original Storeview somehow injects a custom CSS into the Main CSS and i am not able to trace down how this is done.

I searched the source thorougly and tried several tutorials, but for some reason everything i tried didn't work and i wasn't able to get the Custom CSS injected in my copied Storeview.

So my question is: How do i add a custom CSS to the Main CSS in a Storeview properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STORE_[store-code]` layout handle as:

```
<STORE_SomeStoreCode>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/some-custom.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</STORE_SomeStoreCode>
```

Comment: I tried what you told me and put that in the local.xml, but it didn't do anything. I added this: `<STORE_cnh_at>
  <reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>skin/frontend/TTC/CNH - AT/css/styles.css</name></action>
  </reference>
 </STORE_cnh_at>`

Comment: Make sure the css path is correct. Try to inspect if your custom style url is giving 404 error.

Comment: The path does work correct if i access it manually. But if i get it correct, the css file should be added via a link tag and it didn't even add that to the header.

Comment: I just checked and it's working fine for me. Other possible issue can be: 1> Not using proper store code 2> Not using the above xml in correct file or xml node

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I assume local.xml is the correct file, is there a way to debug if the file is in the correct place for the current store view to be affected?

Comment: Don't forget to refresh your Magento cache :)

Comment: Confirmed working in 1.9.3.2. 
Please note that it should be placed outside the <default> handle.